# PHP script might be prevented form uploading file because of permissions : Ubuntu/Linux

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, file-upload

I recently had issues with a PHP upload script that refused to move uploaded files to a permanent directory. After numerous alterations and debugging attempts to the script (that previously worked on another machine), I checked PHP's settings in `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`. and noted everything in there wouldn’t prevent the upload. I then turned to where temporary files are stored (`/tmp`) and found that a tmp file is created when uploading.

Could the script be prevented from moving the file to a location (not one declared default installation of Apache) due to permissions requirements?

I checked what user Apache is using `posix_getpwuid()` and it returned:

```
Array ( 
    [name] => www-data 
    [passwd] => x 
    [uid] => 33 
    [gid] => 33 
    [gecos] => www-data 
    [dir] => /var/www 
    [shell] => /usr/sbin/nologin 
)
```

The directory of the site using the script is `/home/smillification/workspace/Website` and it's permission is set to `me / (smillification)`. Both the upload script and final file location that the script moves the uploaded file to is located under the above mentioned directory.

I am new to Ubuntu and it file permissions so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Is error reporting enabled?

Comment: Nope, no error and error reporting is enabled for that file.

Comment: So the php script just "refused" to move files without saying you anything? Weird.

Comment: I took a closer look at that, restarted Apache and it spewed out:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpUGE44O' to '/home/smilification/workspace/Website/images/adfs_223u.png'

Comment: So it is related to permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixing file permissions for the entire www directory:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/
```

Though I'd advise following [this great answer](https://superuser.com/a/19333) regarding a more permanent permissions fix.

Comment: Because I implemented a virtual host and changed the location of `/var/www` to `/home/smillification/workspace/Website` I substituted the different location in the answer you directed me to. THanks

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance :)